# `com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallException: Install Error: -6` when using in-app updates

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services

I'm trying to implement in-app updates using the play-core library. 
I'm using the dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.5.0'
```

And here is the code I'm using to check for the updates

```
val updateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this)
        updateManager.appUpdateInfo.addOnSuccessListener {
            //code to run is its successful
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            //something wrong happened
            it.printStackTrace()

        }
```

`Onsuccess` is called for some devices but on some `onFailedListener` is called and it throws this error
`com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallException: Install Error: -6`

Answer (score 2):

Check here in the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/install/model/InstallErrorCode.html#error_install_not_allowed)
where `Install Error: -6` means

> The download/install is not allowed, due to the current device state (e.g. low battery, low disk space, ...).
>
> Constant Value: -6 (0xfffffffa)